# Partition pruning/elimination in SAP ASE database

Tags: database, database-partitioning

I want to implement partition pruning for an SAP ASE database, but the partitioning does not seem to get used.

Here is a minimal verifyable example of my problem:

1. I have created a table:

   ```
   create table Employee(
       empId INT not null,
       empName VARCHAR(50) not null,
       CONSTRAINT Employee_bk PRIMARY KEY(empId)
   )
   partition by range (empId)
   (
       Employee_p1 values <= (5),
       Employee_p2 values <= (10),
       Employee_p3 values <= (15),
       Employee_p4 values <= (20)
   )
   ```
2. The following data is inserted into the table:

   ```
   empId  empName
      1  hskf
      6  fdgfh
      8  kygj
     15  zcc
     17  xvx
   ```
3. When I select from the table, the query returns the correct record:

   ```
   1>select * from Employee where empId=6
   2>go

   empId       empName
   ----------- --------------------------------------------------
   6           fdgfh
   ```
4. The problem is that the Query plan shows that the query is scanning all partitions instead of eliminating other partitions scan:

   ```
   STEP 1
   The type of query is SELECT.

   1 operator(s) under root

   |ROOT:EMIT Operator (VA = 1)
   |
   |   |SCAN Operator (VA = 0)
   |   |  FROM TABLE
   |   |  Employee
   |   |  [ Partitions Used: 4, Eliminated: 0]
   |   |  [ Eliminated Partition ids : ]
   |   |  [ Used Partition ids : ]
   |   |  [ Using Dynamic Partition Elimination ]
   |   |  Using Clustered Index.
   |   |  Index : Employee_bk
   |   |  Forward Scan.
   |   |  Positioning by key.
   |   |  Keys are:
   |   |    empId ASC
   |   |  Using I/O Size 2 Kbytes for data pages.
   |   |  With LRU Buffer Replacement Strategy for data pages.
   ```

As per the documentation, the setting *enable semantic partitioning* is set to 1.

**Can anyone please suggest how to eliminate unnecessary partition scan?**

Comment: Are you sure there is enough data in the table to justify anything but a forward scan? Probably the issue here is that partition pruning is simply not beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As per my understanding, partition pruning is not dependant on data size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possible solution is that the database setting

```
basic_optimization_partitions
```

is switched off. Check if this setting is disabled and if the partition pruning works when this is switched on.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. After enabling this parameter - 'basic_optimization_partitions: allow partitioned tables in basic optimization', it worked.